# Unable to create Linux Function Apps (Consumption plan) and Linux App Service Plans and in the same Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

I am unable to create an Azure Function App (hosted on Linux on a Consumption plan) in a Resource Group which already contains 2 App Services hosted on Linux. I am getting an Error (from the Azure portal) saying that the “Requested Feature is not available in the resource group”.
Are there any restrictions in having a dynamic and app service plan on Linux in the same RG?

This is the complete error:
`<b>
{
    "Code": "BadRequest",
    "Message": "Requested feature is not available in resource group *******. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one.",
    "Target": null,
    "Details": [
        {
            "Message": "Requested feature is not available in resource group ********. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one."
        },
        {
            "Code": "BadRequest"
        },
        {
            "ErrorEntity": {
                "ExtendedCode": "59324",
                "MessageTemplate": "Requested feature is not available in resource group {0}. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one.",
                "Parameters": [
                    "************"
                ],
                "Code": "BadRequest",
                "Message": "Requested feature is not available in resource group *******. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one."
            }
        }
    ],
    "Innererror": null
}
</b>`

I have also attached the screengrab of the Function App that I am trying to create:
[image: Event-Store-issue]

Comment: it should work, you can open an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4869

Comment: Can you offer the region , the OS and the type of service plan that you three function used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a Linux Web App in an App Service plan already hosting non-Linux Web Apps.

Based on a current limitation, for the same resource group you cannot mix Windows and Linux apps in the same region.

It is mentioned in Public doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations

More explanation is given here. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Creating-Function-Apps-in-an-existing-Resource-Group

Comment: I am not mixing Windows and Linux here. My Resource Group contains 2 LINUX App Service Plans and I am trying to create another Linux Function App (consumption plan).

Answer (score 2):

Did you find a solution?

I have the same issue when creating it via an ARM template.

There is one way to do it (tried on EU West though):

1. Create a new Resource Group
2. Create your function in the new RG
3. Move your function-plan, storage, and function to the desired RG

I hope it would be possible to create the same plan from ARM or via the interface. Let me know if someone has found a method. I would rather do it via ARM template and therefore can control the name of the plan..

**Edit:**

If you create a consumption plan first and then the app service plan, then it should work too.

**From the interface**: Just create a function app which is a linux version, then the plan should be created. Then add the linux app service plan.

**From ARM:** Just make the app service plan depend on the consumption plan.

I will update if we know more in the future..

Answer (score 0):

As DixitArora says, you can not create both Window OS function and Linux OS function in a same resourcegroup on usual.

**The Key is the service plan and the region.**

**On this way you can create successfully:**

***1.The first way:*** As the Badrequest message show to you, you can recreate a new resource group and put your function app in that new resource group.(will success with consumption plan.)

***2.The second way:*** you can create a function with app service plan, like this:

[image]

(I can create both Linux OS function app and Windows OS function app in the same resource group on my side. Please have a try on your side.)

[image]
   (First is windows OS, consumption app. Second is Linux OS, App Service Plan. These two function are in the same region named 'Central US'.)

***3.The third way:*** If you still want to create a consumption app. Please choose another region which support consumption plan. And then you can create function successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced exactly same issue, trying to deploy Function App(python) from VS code. Below steps helped to successfully deploy into Azure from VS Code.

**Activity at Azure portal:**

- Create a Function App(python) under a consumption plan.
- Add the below into Configuration of your Function App [This setting is required for publishing consumption linux app]

**Key:** `AzureWebJobsStorage`

**Value:**

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={storage account name};AccountKey={storage account access key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

**Activity from VS Code(local):**

- Install Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI), the OS for me was Windows and picked the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/
- Install `Az.Accounts` module:

  ```
  Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser -Name Az.Accounts
  ```
- Login into azure, az login. This will take you to sign-in by the browser.
- Deploy into Azure from VS Code by func azure functionapp publish {your function app name}.